# elevatezoom, image is showing in the container

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/jquery.elevatezoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<img id="zoom_01" src="Images\small\download.jpg" data-zoom-image="Images\large\download1.jpg"/>

<script>
    $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom();
</script>
```

When i move over my mouse to the image, the zoom image should shown in the container, but it just give me a empty box which got no image inside. How to solve this? i followed the instustion given by http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples but it is still not working...
help me on this please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are having an issue because you chose to use a "\" as a path separator, don't do that.

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="Images/small/download.jpg" 
     data-zoom-image="Images/large/download1.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you forget to include jquery lib before including elevatezoom-plugin?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```